# Simulate clicks on options

Tags: javascript

I have a code that selects an option after you clicked an element:

You can see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gMZGr/)

```
function setAsSelectedOption(referrerElement){
  var clickToOptionMap = {
        'click-object-1'  :  'fireaway',
        'click-object-2'  :  'groundearth',
        'click-object-3'  :  'watermelon',
        'click-object-4'  :  'catchwind'
  };
  var optionId = clickToOptionMap[referrerElement.id];
  var optionElement = document.getElementById(optionId);

  optionElement.selected = true;
};
```

I'd like to run a code after this code. That code needs to simulate a click on the top option in the list and then clicks back on the last selected option.

Anyone know of such a script?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simulate clicks on options</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
div
{
width:30px;
height:30px;
margin:4px;
cursor:pointer;
}

#click-object-1{background-color:#F00;}
#click-object-2{background-color:#0F0;}
#click-object-3{background-color:#00F;}
#click-object-4{background-color:#FF0;}
</style>


<body>


<form action="">

  <fieldset>

    <ul style="list-style:none;">
      <li>
        <select id="select_items_first" name="SelectItemsFirst">
          <option value="choose">Please choose</option>
          <option id="fireaway" value="xjakgd">Fire</option>
          <option id="groundearth" value="yuygas">Earth</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li>
        <select id="select_items_second" name="SelectItemsSecond">
          <option value="choosemore">Please choose</option>
          <option id="watermelon" value="piowqe">Water</option>
          <option id="catchwind" value="mnbvzi">Wind</option>
        </select>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </fieldset>

</form>

<div id="click-object-1" onclick="setAsSelectedOption(this)"></div>
<div id="click-object-2" onclick="setAsSelectedOption(this)"></div>

<br />

<div id="click-object-3" onclick="setAsSelectedOption(this)"></div>
<div id="click-object-4" onclick="setAsSelectedOption(this)"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function setAsSelectedOption(referrerElement){
  var clickToOptionMap = {
        'click-object-1'  :  'fireaway',
        'click-object-2'  :  'groundearth',
        'click-object-3'  :  'watermelon',
        'click-object-4'  :  'catchwind'
  };
  var optionId = clickToOptionMap[referrerElement.id];
  var optionElement = document.getElementById(optionId);

  optionElement.selected = true;
};
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

************************************ UPDATE 2011-09-14 ************************************

I made a gif to show what I'd like to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to add the following line to click an element: `document.getElementById("yourid").click();`

In your case, it would be

```
document.getElementById("click-object-1").click();
document.getElementById("click-object-4").click();
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/gMZGr/1/ )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You must see the two select "lists" separately. For example, if you click on click-object-2, the "Earth" option will be selected, and then right after that the "Please choose" option will be clicked followed by a click on the "Earth" option again.

Comment: I don't get it, you mean simulate a visual click?

Comment: It's a bit confusion, you see it's hard to explain. The html code needs to think its a "real" mouse click, you don't actually have to see the mouse moving. For example, the following action takes place when you click on the "click-object-4" element: (1) select _Wind_ option, (2) click _Please choose_ option, (3) click _Wind_ option

Comment: The code I provided does exactly that, it simulates a click on Fire and Wind, resulting in both of them being chosen in the select.

Comment: Both `<select>'s` must have "Please choose" selected. Then, if you click, for example, the `<div id="click-object-3">` element, you would see (if you could see it in slow motion) the selected option change to _Water_, then to _Please choose_, and finally back to _Water_ again. This only happens when you click on one of the colored squares, and each square has a different outcome.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Works perfectly in Firefox, but it doesn't work in ie6,7,8 :(  Do you have any idea why?

Comment: What exactly is happening in ie? (i don't have one rigth now)

Comment: For example: if you click _Fire_, it selects _Fire_, but it doesn't switch from _Fire_ to _Please choose_ and back to _Fire_ again. I don't get an error or something, so I don't know exactly what is causing the problem. Maybe it's `setTimeout`, but I don't know. Can `setTimeout` be replaced?

Comment: Nope, from what I found, ie has a weird behavior on some select properties. You could try: http://jsfiddle.net/gMZGr/6/

Comment: Sadly doesn't work :( Thanks for trying though! If you ever find a way to make it work in ie6,7,8 please let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var select = optionElement.parentNode;
select.firstElementChild.click();
select.lastElementChild.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nicola. It didn't seem to work though. The code has to work as follows: if you click on click-object-2, the "Earth" option will be selected, and then right after that the "Please choose" option will be clicked followed by a click on the "Earth" option again. If your click on "click-object-1", it goes Fire --> Please choose --> Fire. If your click on "click-object-3", it goes Water --> Please choose --> Water. Etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily, accomplish that with the use of `setTimeout`.

It may be tricky when the user clicks another color square in the middle of the "animation". but its not that difficult. http://jsfiddle.net/pdWFX/1/

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Yes, I'm using the code @Py. made: http://jsfiddle.net/gMZGr/4, he also uses setTimeout. It doesn't seem to work in ie6, I think setTimeout isn't compatible with ie6. Do you know a way to make the script work in ie6?

Comment: Thanks @GerManson, there are a few problems though: Water and Wind don't work correctly, your script doesn't use `<option value="choosemore">` for the change of Water and Wind. The code doesn't seem to work outside jsfiddle.net